# Hibernate Hql for bulk update using two entity tables

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, hql

I am using this query in mysql for updating multiple values for the `column2` in `Table1` with the values in the `column2` in `Table2` on certain condition. but i am not able to give two entity names in the hibernate update hql. can i know how i have to write the query below in hql so that it supports all database.

```
UPDATE Table1 A, Table2 B SET A.column2 = B.column2 WHERE A.column1 = B.column1
```

Thanks,
Saif

Comment: My requirement is for updating mutiple records in one table with the value from another table on matching certain criteria and my mysql query looks like                                                          UPDATE table1 A, table2 B SET A.field6 = B.field6 
WHERE A.field1 = B.field1 
AND A.field2 = B.field2 
AND A.field3 = B.field3 
AND A.field4 = B.field4 
AND A.field5=B.field5                                              is there any way to write this query through hibernate                                                            Thanks, Saif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Hibernate 4.1.9 manual - section about bulk update and deletes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> No implicit or explicit joins can be specified in a bulk HQL query.
> Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries
> themselves may contain joins.

Unsupported (implicit join):

```
DELETE A a WHERE a.relation.property = "dummy";
```

A way to go:

```
DELETE A a WHERE a.relation.id IN (SELECT r.id FROM Relation r WHERE r.property = "dummy");
```

For your example it is bit complicated but following query should work (tested in HSQL db):

```
UPDATE A a SET a.column3 = (SELECT b.column3 FROM B b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2) WHERE a.id IN (SELECT a.id FROM A a, B b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2)
```

This query works in HSQL db, but fails in MySQL. It looks like that only possible solution is to use two separate queries:

```java
List<String> list = em.createQuery("SELECT a.column1 FROM A a, B b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2").getResultList();
em.createQuery("UPDATE A a SET a.column3 = (SELECT b.column3 FROM B b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 and a.column2 = b.column2) WHERE a.column1 IN :list").setParameter("list", list).executeUpdate();
```

The last solution is tested in mysql and works well but in your case you have to customize first select query based on your use case - my example expects that a.column1 is unique (using column1 instead of id to avoid primary key).

Comment: My requirement is for updating mutiple records and my mysql query looks like                                                     UPDATE table1 A, table2 B SET A.field6 = B.field6 
WHERE A.field1 = B.field1 
AND A.field2 = B.field2 
AND A.field3 = B.field3 
AND A.field4 = B.field4 
AND A.field5 =B.field5                                                            is there any way to write this query through hibernate

Comment: I've added example for your use case.

Comment: thank you..but can we do the query if both the tables are having composite key. in the example above i think id is the primary key for table A.

Comment: You can change `WHERE` part of the query for example to: `a.column1 IN (SELECT a.column1 FROM A a, B b WHERE a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2)` - not tested but it is almost identical to example provided and avoids using id as primary key.

Comment: OK, the query works with hsql db but not with mysql ... interesting. It tried using mysql and added another solution.